# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{2(1-\cos(7ax))}{7ax^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{2(1-\cos(7ax))}{7ax^2}$$

Is there a solution using trig identities?

Comment: @JoJomax Read the question and the tags.

Comment: Use $$\cos2A=1-?$$

Answer (score 3):

With high-school tools:
$$\frac{2(1-\cos 7ax )}{7ax^2}=\frac{2(1-\cos^2 7ax )}{7ax^2(1+\cos 7ax)}=\frac{2\cdot 7a}{\underbrace{1+\cos 7ax}_{\substack{\downarrow\\7a}}}\biggl(\underbrace{\frac{\sin 7ax}{7ax}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1}}\biggr)^2$$

*Addendum*:

It is also very simple with the more sophisticated notion of *equivalent functions*: we  have this basic equivalence:
$\enspace1-\cos u \sim_0\dfrac{u^2}2,$
whence, by the usual rules of *asymptotic calculus*,
$$\frac{2(1-\cos 7ax )}{7ax^2}\sim_0\frac{2}{7ax^2}\frac{(7ax)^2}{2}=7a.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{split}\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{2(1-\cos7ax)}{7ax^2} &=
\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{4\sin^2(\frac{7ax}{2})}{7ax^2}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}7a\frac{\sin^2(\frac{7ax}{2})}{(\frac{7ax}{2})^2}\\
&=7a \end{split}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $2t = 7ax$ (i.e. $t =7ax/2$). Then you have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{2(1-\cos(7ax))}{7ax^2}={2\over 7a}\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{49a^2(1-\cos(2t))}{4t^2}$$

$$ ={7a\over 2}\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{2\sin^2t}{t^2}={7a}$$